# TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь подготовить данные для построения модели LDA.
Данный код

```py
 df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.data, columns=wine.feature_names)
 df3_class = wine.target
```

выдает ошибку:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'.
```

Мой путь решения данной ошибки это написания дополнительного кода:

```py
X = df1[['satisfaction_level', 'last_evaluation', 'number_project', 'average_montly_hours', 'time_spend_company', 'Work_accident', 'promotion_last_5years']]
y = df1.iloc['left']
```

Код не решил проблему, а выдал следующую ошибку:

```
Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

Какие требуются преобразования данных для исключения указанных ошибок не знаю. Дополнительно размещаю информацию о данных:

```
df2.dropna().info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 14999 entries, 0 to 14998
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------  -----  
 0   satisfaction_level     14999 non-null  float64
 1   last_evaluation        14999 non-null  float64
 2   number_project         14999 non-null  int64  
 3   average_montly_hours   14999 non-null  int64  
 4   time_spend_company     14999 non-null  int64  
 5   Work_accident          14999 non-null  int64  
 6   left                   14999 non-null  int64  
 7   promotion_last_5years  14999 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(2), int64(6)
memory usage: 1.0 MB
```

Прошу помочь!

Comment: исправленные  неточности в коде не решает вопрос. Исправления кода: df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.data, columns=df2.feature_names)
df3_class = df2.target

Comment: Скорее всего указанная ошибка из-за `df1.iloc['left'] ` так как _.iloc[] is primarily integer position based_. Или вместо `iloc` возьмите `loc`, либо вместо "left" укажите целочисленный индекс. В остальной ваш код не вникал.